# Use a JButton to close the application open currently

Tags: java, swing, jframe

What I want to do is have a `JButton` and when you click on it, it will close the `JFrame`/Application. I have a `JButton` made but I want to know how to make it close the window open currently.

Comment: 1) Use [`setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29).  The 'button' (on the top right of frame) comes built-in. 2) *"Thanks, Noah"*  Noise, leave it out.

Answer (score 3):

Register a listener to your button and then call System.exit(0) on the button click.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Close");
button.addActionLister(new ActionListener(){

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       System.exit(0);
  }
});
```

Comment: *"There might be some syntax changes since i am writing this code without an IDE"*  Not bad, given you typed it from ..memory, experience.. whatever.  I made some tweaks to it after using my compiler to check the detail.

Answer (score 2):

In the `actionPerformed()` of the `JButton`, just add `System.exit(0)`. You are good to go.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh, yes. Non-zero means abnormal termination.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Kinda hard to shrug off the MR. but .. I think you should have left 'noise' there.

Comment: Eh (shrugs) If the person edits the answer to include the advice (which is my preference) the comment becomes noise.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the dispose() method of your JFrame. See its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29).

Addendum: Also, you might want so set the default close operation of the JFrame to "exit" instead of the default "hide". Do it when you create your frame.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

// Do whatever your application does.

frame.dispose();    // With this you close the frame.
```

Comment: *"..to "exit" instead of the default "hide"."*  Even better is `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.  It will only exit the VM after all non-daemon threads finish running.  If the VM keeps running indefinitely after frame close, it is a sign there are threads that the programmer needs to explicitly clean up/shut down.

Answer (score 1):

See the `ExitAction` from [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/).

This approach is a little different from the other suggestions as it will dispatch the windowClosing() event to the Window. This will cause the window to close based on the close option of the window and will invoke any window listeners you may have added to the window to handle the windowClosing() event.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the dispose() method of JFrame, followed by System.exit(0)

Comment: This message was meant for Dinukadev

Comment: This message was meant for Dinukadev

Comment: I don't think so, this is part of the OS. Maybe you can create a own look & feel and set it explicitly for your application.

Comment: *"Also, is there a way to have no close operation"* Umm.. you might try following the link in the first comment to the question..  Reading the fine manual can reveal much.

Answer (score 0):

make an object from the class that contains the JFrame application and then `dispose` it in a button event listener:

**for ex.**

```
    public class Application extends JFrame {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        static  Application app= new Application ();

    public Application{
       setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       Container pane =this.getContentPane();

       JPanel right = new JPanel();
       right.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));



       ButtonEvent = new JButton("Button");
       right.add(whiteList);


       pane.add(right);

 }

    public class ButtonEvent implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
        app.dispose();
        dispose();
    }

 }


public static void main(String args[]){
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    app.setVisible(true);
    app.setTitle("Application");
    app.setSize(700,500);
    app.setLocation(350, 100);
    }
}
```